# Why do I keep getting LNK2005/Duplicates in C

Tags: c

I'm learning C and I'm struggling with understanding declarations vs definitions - especially when I have to define/declare them just once, otherwise risking build failure.

For example, I'm writing a BST, and I keep getting the LNK2005 (Visual Studio) error. I don't really understand what this means, why I'm getting it, or how to fix it. From my view, I have defined and separated my prototypes and functions once, but I get multiple errors regarding bst.h declarations already being defined in my bst.c file.

Any help is appreciated!

**main:**

```
#include "bst.c"

int main() {
    BST tree = new_bst();
    int quit = 0;
    int data;
    while (quit == 0) {
        printf("Enter some data: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &data);
        if (data != 0) {
            insert_bst(&tree, data);
        }
        else {
            quit = 1;
        }
    }
    print_pre_order_bst(&tree);
    printf("\n");
    print_in_order_bst(&tree);
    printf("\n");
    print_post_order_bst(&tree);
    printf("\n");
}
```

**bst.h**

```
#pragma once

typedef struct bstNode {
    int data_item;
    struct bstNode* left;
    struct bstNode* right;
} *BSTNodePtr;

typedef struct bst {
    BSTNodePtr root;
} BST;

BST new_bst();

BSTNodePtr find_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, int n);

BSTNodePtr find_bst(BST* self, int n);

BSTNodePtr insert_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, int n);

void insert_bst(BST* self, int n);

BSTNodePtr min_node(BSTNodePtr self);

BSTNodePtr delete_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, int n);

void delete_bst(BST* self, int n);

void print_pre_order_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self);

void print_pre_order_bst(BST* self);

void print_in_order_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self);

void print_in_order_bst(BST* self);

void print_post_order_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self);

void print_post_order_bst(BST* self);
```

**bst.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bst.h"

BST new_bst() {
    BST temp;
    temp.root = NULL;
    return temp;
}

BSTNodePtr find_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, int n) {
    if (self == NULL || (n == self->data_item)) {
        return self;
    }
    else if (n < self->data_item) {
        return find_bst_node(self->left, n);
    }
    else {
        return find_bst_node(self->right, n);
    }
}

BSTNodePtr find_bst(BST* self, int n) {
    return find_bst_node(self->root, n);
}

BSTNodePtr insert_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, int n) {
    if (self == NULL) { // found where to put it
        self = malloc(sizeof * self);
        self->data_item = n;
        self->left = self->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (n < self->data_item) {
        self->left = insert_bst_node(self->left, n);
    }
    else if (n > self->data_item) {
        self->right = insert_bst_node(self->right, n);
    }
    return self;
}

void insert_bst(BST* self, int n) {
    self->root = insert_bst_node(self->root, n);
}

BSTNodePtr min_node(BSTNodePtr self) {
    BSTNodePtr current = self;
    while (current->left != NULL) {
        current = current->left;
    }
    return current;
}

BSTNodePtr delete_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, int n) {
    if (self != NULL) {
        if (n == self->data_item) {
            if (self->left != NULL && self->right != NULL) {
                // two child case
                BSTNodePtr successor = min_node(self->right);
                self->data_item = successor->data_item;
                self->right = delete_bst_node(self->right, self->data_item);
            }
            else {
                BSTNodePtr to_free = self;
                if (self->left) {
                    self = self->left;
                }
                else {
                    self = self->right;
                }
                free(to_free);
            }
        }
        else if (n < self->data_item) {
            self->left = delete_bst_node(self->left, n);
        }
        else {
            self->right = delete_bst_node(self->right, n);
        }
    }
    return self;
}

void delete_bst(BST* self, int n) {
    self->root = delete_bst_node(self->root, n);
}

void print_pre_order_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self) {
    if (self != NULL) {
        printf("(");
        printf(" %d ", self->data_item);
        print_pre_order_bst_node(self->left);
        print_pre_order_bst_node(self->right);
        printf(")");
    }
    else {
        printf("_");
    }
}

void print_pre_order_bst(BST* self) {
    print_pre_order_bst_node(self->root);
}

void print_in_order_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self) {
    if (self != NULL) {
        printf("(");
        print_in_order_bst_node(self->left);
        printf(" %d ", self->data_item);
        print_in_order_bst_node(self->right);
        printf(")");
    }
    else {
        printf("_");
    }
}

void print_in_order_bst(BST* self) {
    print_in_order_bst_node(self->root);
}

void print_post_order_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self) {
    if (self != NULL) {
        printf("(");
        print_post_order_bst_node(self->left);
        print_post_order_bst_node(self->right);
        printf(" %d ", self->data_item);
        printf(")");
    }
    else {
        printf("_");
    }
}

void print_post_order_bst(BST* self) {
    print_post_order_bst_node(self->root);
}
```

Comment: Try removing `#include "bst.c"` from main.c

Comment: ... and include `bst.h` in `main.c`

Comment: Note: the compiler you are using conforms to C89, but not C99,C11, C17.  To well learn C, you might want to use a more up-to-date compiler.